# Preserve JSON arrays while sorting

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, sorting

I have two JSON arrays coming from an external website. I sort and merge the two arrays, decode them and then sort them from highest to lowest by ID.

Currently, when the option 'alphabetical' is clicked, `?sort=alphabetical` is added onto the end of the URL and when the page has finished reloading, the JSON arrays are once again decoded and merged.

This is not my desired outcome: I do not want the JSON arrays to be decoded and merged again when the option is clicked - I simply want the already decoded and merged JSON arrays to be sorted alphabetically.

---

Arrays:

```
$homepage = array();  

$homepage[]= '{  
   "info":{  
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Charlie",
            "ID":"7"
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Emma",
            "ID":"9"
         }
      ]
   }
}';  

$homepage[] = '{  
   "info":{  
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Bob",
            "ID":"5"
         }
      ]
   }
}';
```

---

Sorting:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
    $tmp=json_decode($homepage2, false);
    $data = array_merge($data,$tmp->info->collection);
}

if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'alphabetical') {
    usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->Name, $b->Name);
    });
}else{
    usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
        return $b->ID - $a->ID;
    });
}

echo'
<select onchange="location.href = this.value;">
    <option value="example.php?sort=alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
</select>
';

foreach($data as $key) {
    echo'
    <a href="test.com">
    <p>'.$key->ID.'</p>
    <p>'.$key->Name.'</p>
    </a>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I for one can't seem to decipher what you're getting at.

Comment: @JonStirling I thought that may be a problem.. I was also unsure how to word it. When the user selects 'alphabetically', the page is refreshed and the two JSON arrays are merged and then decoded - how would I stop all this from happening, but simply sort the data alphabetically (without merging and decoding the data when the page refreshes)

Comment: @TheCodesee if you want to change the contents of the page without refreshing you'll almost certainly have to write some JavaScript to do so - unless you wanted to create another request to the server and replace the contents of the page.

Comment: @PWhite I'm not so bothered about the page refreshing, it's mainly having to decode and merge the json arrays again.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to decode/merge the array of JSON strings again? It isn't a big performance problem and the only way to avoid this is storing the decoded/merged data somewhere (like a PHP session or DB), but that seems like it'll just bring on more problems than not.

Comment: @Sam Good question. As I mentioned in my post, I am getting the json data from an external url (I posted an example of the json file in this question to make it easier to understand). I am worried that the server will block me if I make too many requests.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense...I missed the external part. Well, you could save it in a database or PHP session -- but I still don't think that's the write answer. Are you okay integrating JavaScript into your app? It would be much easier for the PHP script to fetch, decode, and merge the data and then have JS handle the sorting on the fly.

Comment: @Sam I suppose so, I had seen some other answers recommending Javascript but I originally wrote the code in PHP as I don't have much experience/knowledge of coding with JavaScript.

Comment: Could you give the exact way how you output the `ID` and `Name` values? I don't suppose you just output them like that without HTML? Javascript-based solutions need to know the exact HTML structure you put them in.

Comment: Sorry, @trincot. Check my updated question.

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your question? Could you leave a comment or accept the answer of your choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use JavaScript for doing the sorting on click, and use PHP only for passing the JSON to it.

After you provided the HTML structure you want to display the list in, I updated this answer to use `div` elements for the records and `p` elements for the fields.

We could replace the `select` list, for selecting the sort order, by two buttons.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$homepage = array();  

$homepage[]= '{  
   "info":{  
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Charlie",
            "ID":"13"
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Emma",
            "ID":"9"
         }
      ]
   }
}';  

$homepage[] = '{  
   "info":{  
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Bob",
            "ID":"10"
         }
      ]
   }
}';

$data = array();
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
    $tmp=json_decode($homepage2, false);
    $data = array_merge($data,$tmp->info->collection);
}

?>

<div id="container"></div>

<button id="sort1">Alphabetical</button>
<button id="sort2">High to Low</button>

<script>
    var collection = <?=json_encode($data)?>;

    function populate(compareFunc) {
        collection.sort(compareFunc);
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.innerHTML = '';
        collection.forEach(function (key) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "inventory";
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.textContent = key.ID;
            div.appendChild(span);
            span = document.createElement("span");
            span.textContent = key.Name;
            div.appendChild(span);
            container.appendChild(div);
        });
    }

    var populateById = populate.bind(null, function (a, b) {
        return a.ID - b.ID;
    });

    var populateByName = populate.bind(null, function (a, b) {
        return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
    });

    document.getElementById("sort1").addEventListener('click', populateByName);
    document.getElementById("sort2").addEventListener('click', populateById);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', populateById);

</script>
```

For the sample data this will result in the following JavaScript/HTML, which you can test here:

```js
var collection = [{"Name":"Charlie","ID":"13"},{"Name":"Emma","ID":"9"},{"Name":"Bob","ID":"10"}];

function populate(compareFunc) {
    collection.sort(compareFunc);
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    collection.forEach(function (key) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "inventory";
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.textContent = key.ID;
        div.appendChild(span);
        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.textContent = key.Name;
        div.appendChild(span);
        container.appendChild(div);
    });
}

var populateById = populate.bind(null, function (a, b) {
    return a.ID - b.ID;
});

var populateByName = populate.bind(null, function (a, b) {
    return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
});

document.getElementById("sort1").addEventListener('click', populateByName);
document.getElementById("sort2").addEventListener('click', populateById);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', populateById);
```

```css
span { margin-left: 5px }
div.inventory { border-bottom: 1px solid gray }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<button id="sort1">Alphabetical</button>
<button id="sort2">High to Low</button>
```

Note that I gave the three items different ID values than in your question, since otherwise the sort order would be the same for both ID and Name.

#### Using tables: alternative

There are nice JavaScript libraries which give much more features to represent data sets. Here is an example using jQuery with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/):

```js
var collection = [{"Name":"Charlie","ID":"13"},{"Name":"Emma","ID":"9"},{"Name":"Bob","ID":"5"}];

function populate() {
  var tbody = $('#collection>tbody');
  collection.forEach(function (key) {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    row.append($('<td>').text(key.ID));
    row.append($('<td>').text(key.Name));
    tbody.append(row);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  populate();
  $('#collection').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="collection">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody/>
</table>
```

The actual code is even smaller (not counting the included library) than a pure JavaScript solution would be with a basic table. But this has sorting up and down, filtering, pagination, nice styles, ...

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent response, I truly wasn't expecting it! I apologize for not making my question clearer. Rather than displaying the results in tables, I'm displaying them inside a div element. From your code, I have modified it to fit my needs: https://jsfiddle.net/jknj4uat/1/ (could you please update your post) - thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I am happy to adjust my answer, but the HTML you now ask for in the question includes `a` and `p` tags, while the jsfiddle you point to only outputs the name, not the ID, and without those `a` and `p` tags. So it is different on almost all aspects. What exactly do you want? ;-)

Comment: Anyway, I have updated my post. Note that it is better to use `textContent` than `innerHTML` when it concerns unformatted text. I've also used `bind` to create two flavours of the `populate` function, which now accepts as argument the function to sort with.

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives for this answer, so I will present a simple one:

Send the data already sorted, a default one, if the user made no choices. Then, set a function that sorts the data as needed, and redraws tables/divs/whatever you are using to present them.

As an quick example:

```
function sortAlpha(){
   for each (stuff in data){
      document.getElementById("aTable").textContent=data.StringRepresentation;
   }
}
```

Then a function for sortSize, sortEtc, etc... in each function, you clear a div content, and populate it again. This way, you do not need to request new content from servers

[getElementById documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Yup, JS is the best (really the only, if a database isn't being used to store data) solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions in which you can achieve the desired results. 
If you want it pure **PHP** way what you can do is save the data in **PHP Sessions** and retrive them as need.

Here is the trick comes, You create function to get the result data in which you pass single parameter whether you want to get the data from external URL or from your saved data.

Now, in your application whenever you want to refresh the saved data call the same function with parameter denoting to refresh the saved data in **SESSIONS** to get replaced with data from external source.

Using this method you can reuse the data you've already fetched from external source without re-fetching it every-time you reload the function.

You can make another function which will return true for all cases in which application has to re-fetch the resultset from external source.

I've written pseudo code for you to understand what I'm trying to convey,

Function check whether we've to re-fetch the result from external source:

```
function hasToRefreshResult() {
        if(/* CERTAIN CONDITIONS */) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Couple of functions to get the data from local/external source according to the parameter passed:

```
    function getResultArray($getdatafromlocal) {
        if(!hasToRefreshResult() && $getdatafromlocal && array_key_exists("filertereddata",$_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION["filertereddata"])) {
            $data=$_SESSION["filertereddata"];
        } else {
            $data=getDataFromExternalURL();
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'alphabetical') {
            usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
                return strcmp($a->Name, $b->Name);
            });
        } else {
            usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
                return $b->ID - $a->ID;
            });
        }

        return $data;
    }

    function getDataFromExternalURL() {
        /*****
           YOUR LOGIC TO GET DATA FROM EXTERNAL URL;
         *****/

        $data = array();
        foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
            $tmp=json_decode($homepage2, false);
            $data = array_merge($data,$tmp->info->collection);
        }
        $_SESSION["filertereddata"]=$data;
        return $data;
    }
```

I hope this will solve your issue strictly using **PHP**.
Also don't forget the write `session_start();` at the top of the **PHP** file you will be using this functions.

Comment: Could you confirm whether when the user reloads the page WITHOUT sorting, it will decode and merge the array?

Comment: Yes it can be done. Just call the function to get data. When the function doesn't find the data in sessions it will get it from the external source. And when it finds the data in sessions it will return the data from sessions only and you can perform whatever sorting you would like to.

Comment: So according to your requirement it won't execute multiple requests to external source.

Comment: So `if(empty($data)) {`

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you!

Comment: Session variables should only be used for information relevant to the user, and/or needed by multiple disconnected components. it is VERY bad practice to use them as a data-dumping ground.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Are you saying I shouldn't use this answer?

Comment: @The Cosesee you can use this method in sessions. We're not using it for data dump, we're using for the track of the data fetched from external site by USER according their filter. Though you can use files here too but sessions are also fine.

Comment: @TheCodesee I'm saying you should either use trincot 's javascript solution, or use PHP to dump the sorted result into javascript. There's no need to put this data in sessions.