# HTML text as POST toggle (kinda like a radio button)?

Tags: php, html, post

I have this on my site:
[image]

I want to be able to sort the servers by pressing on players, maps etc.
So to explain it better; If I press once one players I want the list to be ordered in descending order and if I press again I want it to be in ascending order. I already have a script for this and it works with radio buttons, however, that doesn't fit my design. Also, I don't want to need to press another button after the text is clicked on, I want it to change the sorting instantly.

My code for this is:
PHP:

```
        if(isset($_POST['sort']))
    {
        if($_POST['sort'] == 'Players Descending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $b['Players'] <=> $a['Players'];
                });  
        }
        if($_POST['sort'] == 'Players Ascending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $a['Players'] <=> $b['Players'];
                });  
        }
    }
```

and the HTML/PHP

```
    <form method="post">
    </select>
        Sort by:
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="Players Descending">Players Descending
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="Players Ascending">Players Ascending
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter"/>
    </form>
```

Do anyone have any tips on how to do this the way I want it? Thanks!

Comment: I placed a bounty on my question like this a year or two ago.. may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863071/preserve-json-arrays-while-sorting

Comment: Have you tried sorting with JavaScript?

Comment: @The Codesee Thanks for the link, I will read through it. Yes I have, however, I didn't manage to get it fully working. Would Javascript be the solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored into a table, which is what i'm sopposing looking at 
the photo you posted, check this js code:

```
function sortTable() {
 var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 switching = true;
 /* Make a loop that will continue until
 no switching has been done: */
 while (switching) {
   // Start by saying: no switching is done:
   switching = false;
   rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
   /* Loop through all table rows (except the
   first, which contains table headers): */
   for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
  // Start by saying there should be no switching:
     shouldSwitch = false;
  /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
  one from current row and one from the next: */
  x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
  y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
  // Check if the two rows should switch place:
  if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
    // I so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
  }
}
if (shouldSwitch) {
  /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
  and mark that a switch has been done: */
  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
  switching = true;
   }
 }
  }
```

Now edit the "mytable" name with your table name, this should work when you click on the column name (the th tag). Cheers!